# Avoid loosing values from admin product custom fields in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, admin, custom-fields

In Woocommerce, I have added a some custom fields in admin product pages under general settings tab and it works. However, I've added some 3rd party plugin which deletes everything that has been saved in these fields every time an order is processed.

The default fields on the general tab and even another 3rd party's fields are not deleted. I'm wondering if there is a better way to create the fields and store that data than the way that I am doing it.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'mpq_add_location_textbox_to_products' );        

function mpq_add_location_textbox_to_products() {           
    if ( (has_term( 'workshops', 'product_cat' ) )){     
        woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( array( 
            'id' => 'mpq_location', 
            'class' => '', 
            'label' => 'Location:',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter Location'
            ) 
        );      
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'mpq_save_location_textbox_to_post_meta' );

function mpq_save_location_textbox_to_post_meta( $product_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;
    if ( isset( $_POST['mpq_location'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'mpq_location', $_POST['mpq_location'] );
    } else delete_post_meta( $product_id, 'mpq_location' );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some mistakes and missing things… Try the following instead that should solve your issue:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'add_location_product_custom_textaread_field' );
function add_location_product_custom_textaread_field() {
    global $post;

    $term = 'workshops'; // Product category term slug

    if ( has_term( $term, 'product_cat', $post->ID ) ){
        woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( array(
            'id' => '_mpq_location',
            'class' => '',
            'label' => 'Location:',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter Location'
        ) );

        echo '<input type="hidden" name="_mpq_location_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce() . '">';
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post_product', 'save_location_product_custom_textaread_field', 20, 1 );
function save_location_product_custom_textaread_field( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST[ '_mpq_location_nonce' ] ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ '_mpq_location_nonce' ] ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['_mpq_location'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_mpq_location', sanitize_textarea_field($_POST['_mpq_location']) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> I have changed the meat key to `_mpq_location` and removed the `else delete_post_meta()`